# Configuring grails datasources with username and password from OS environment

Tags: grails, passwords, datasource

I am currently working on a grails application. Previously I have been using Django alot to create webapps. In django you can easily create settings that are collected from the OS environment. I find that to be an easy solution for making sure that you don't check in usernames and passwords into the source code repository.

So what I would like to do is in the DataSource.groovy be able to lift in the username and password from the OS environment. Has anyone done anything like this, or is this not the way to go forward?

If this is not the "grails way", how is it supposed to be done, because having the username and password in the repository just feels wrong?

Comment: Not sure about Grails but in Spring, you use a PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer. Then you can use OS envars in your config files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write code in DataSource.groovy and Config.groovy to get env variable and then set username password and other things. I always to it for my production app, sample code is as follows
//Eample is based on url structure like "mysql://username:password@host/database?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"

```
dataSource {
            String mysqlUrl = System.getenv("DATABASE_URL")
            println ">>>>>> Got DATABASE_URL: ${mysqlUrl} <<<<<<<"

            URI dbUri = new URI(mysqlUrl);
            username = dbUri.userInfo.split(":")[0]
            password = dbUri.userInfo.split(":")[1]

            String databaseUrl = "jdbc:${dbUri.scheme}://${dbUri.host}${dbUri.path}"
            if (dbUri.port > 0) {
                databaseUrl += ":${dbUri.port}"
            }

            String query = dbUri.query ?: "reconnect=true"
            query += "&autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
            databaseUrl += "?${query}"
            url = databaseUrl
            dialect = 'org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect'
        }
```

This is one of the way I am sure there must be some simpler way to do this.

**PS: I find it simple though :)**

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was looking for! I didn't realize you could write that advanced code in the DataSource.groovy file. That's excellent!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a environment variable in Windows. Example **DBCONNGRAILS**. In config.groovy (...\grails-app\conf\config.groovy) you can use something like

```
def myConnectionString = System.getenv(DBCONNGRAILS)
```

**WARNING:** If you get variables from the environment(Windows) there will no problem when loading the value when in development. But when you are working with a production server, there will be cases when you will need to resart the OS for tomcat to be able to pick up the changes. I would recommend externalizing the config files.

Comment: Fair point Omar. However like I said, I would mostly be using this for things that will not change very often (passwords to database, email configuration and so on). At least that's how I do it in django.

And I can't do that directly in the DataSource.groovy file can I?

Comment: I have seen it done directly in the datasource, heroku does it that way. But I still believe it might be better to do it in the config file. Here is an example  of how it is done in heroku: [Grails on heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-grails#configure-dependencies).

Comment: Thanks Omar! I have now tried the solution I accepted above, and will be using that.

Answer (score 0):

You can externalized the configuration in any other place and load/merge it simply in your application configuration.

Comment: Ok. That is what I also have seen when I have been googling, but I think it's a very cumbersome way to do something that should be easy. I would like to create a DataSource.groovy file that contains username = System.getenv(DB_USERNAME)

Answer (score 0):

We use [JNDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) at work for exactly this scenario.  We have `context.xml` files located within the individual server's Tomcat directories.  The `context.xml` contains the datasource properties and then within the `datasource` closure (defined in `Datasource.groovy`), the `jndiName` property is set accordingly.

More Links about JNDI:

- http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.7/guide/conf.html#JNDIDataSources
- http://grails.asia/how-to-make-grails-use-jndi-datasource-with-tomcat